# Spring boot @ConfigurationProperties not loaded during start up as a result it's returing null

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

I am working with @Configuration properties with spring boot version 2.4.2. Application start up seems to be fine but properties are not getting loaded as map. Please find the sample code in below snippets

**ApisConfig.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "apis")
@Component
@ToString
public class ApisConfig {
    private Map<String, String> apisMap =new HashMap<>();

    public String getRouteDetails(String key){
        return this.apisMap.get(key);
    }
}
```

Below is the main application where spring boot is annotated

```
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = {"com.demo"})
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ApisConfig.class)
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ApisConfig apisConfig;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        apisConfig.getRouteDetails("qna");
    }
}
```

Following is the properties file located under src/main/resources

```
apis.apisMap.qna=10.0.0.254
apis.apisMap.adapter=10.0.0.254
server.port=6165
```

Following are the tools I am using for building

- Gradle
- IntelliJ Idea
- Spring boot 2.4.2

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried debugging and is the map empty when the app starts up?

Comment: yes it is empty I have implemented command line runner and added break point inside run() method and evaluated the statement it is null and map is empty @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: what is the project structure. In which package both the files are presented.

Comment: com.demo; =>  DemoApplication
com.demo.config; => ApisConfig

Comment: You can remove `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableConfigurationProperties` in  `DemoApplication`. As you are the same package. Tried after that and update here.

Comment: Is Lombok configured correctly in your app? Without the getters and setters that it should generate, Spring Boot won’t be able to see the `apisMap` property. While you diagnose the problem, I’d recommend simplifying things by removing the use of Lombok and writing the getters and setters yourself.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Thank you for your pointer. Lombok was not set properly, because of which the apisMap is not getting picked properly. I have fixed it and started to work like a gem.

Comment: Thank you @GnanaJeyam for your inputs as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution for this. @AndyWilkinson Thank you for your pointer. Lombok was not set properly, because of which the apisMap is not getting picked properly. I have fixed it and started to work like a gem. I have added following dependencies to build.gradle file and started to work

```
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
```

Comment: an alternative to setting a dependency is via a plugin: e.g. `plugins { id 'io.freefair.lombok' version '5.3.3.3' }`